# Web.config fail to transform on TFS 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

I currently work on a *MVC 4.0* project that was *upgraded to MVC 5.0* using the [official guide](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2).

I use Visual Studio 2012 locally and a publish profile was created for the project.

Locally I call msbuild via the *Visual Studio developer command prompt using*: `msbuild /m /p:Configuration=Dev;DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Dev my-solution.sln`

All projects in the solutions do have a Dev configuration and there is a web.dev.config.

The command line on the server is the same.

So far the difference is that on the server only the visual studio shell is installed (not the full) and we cannot install the full instance of VS2012 on the server.

Also, seeing on the install of TFS on the server, I discovered that only v9.0 target files were installed (Visual Studio 2008). Copying Visual Studio 2012 target files do not fix this problem.

I see 2 solutions so far but searching for a third.

- Install full Visual Studio 2012 instance
- Update csproj to include a target transformConfigFiles (basically copy and paste the content of the "Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" section) or import the file via a  declaration inside of the .csproj

Would there be a third solution available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty common to install full Visual Studio on your build server.  As of VS 2012 you couldn't even run Unit Tests in your build without VS installed.

I'd suggest installing VS and seeing if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I assume that you mean as VS2010? Considering we can run tests currently without the full VS2012 installed.